# asp.net core / html - a href not working until every image on page is loaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am having web shop with a lot of images displayed at home page (421). My problem is that when user enters page, and let's say he see where he needs to go after 1 sec and click on link (which is `<a href=...)`, that link won't open until all images on page are loaded and little circle in chrome is stopped loading.

What can i do to overcome this?

`live example at https://beta.termodom.rs` ( select left red button under "Jednokratna kupovina" labeled "Zapocni" and press "proizvodi" in top menu) (it is beta version and i am testing new stuff on it so it may be slower than usually)

here is `index.cshtml`

```
@model int
@{
    List<AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>> Roba = AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>.BufferedList();
    if(Roba == null || Roba.Count == 0)
    {
        Roba = AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>.List(null);
    }

    Roba.Sort((x, y) => y.DisplayIndex.CompareTo(x.DisplayIndex));
}

<style>
    .Groups {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .Group {
        float: left;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: black;
    }

        .Group:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .Pretraga {
        width: 97%;
        margin: 1%;
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
        border-color: #ff5b5b;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>

<div class="Groups">
    @foreach (AR.WebShop.Group g in AR.WebShop.Group.BufferedList())
    {
        <a class="Group" data-groupID="-1" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje...'); window.location.href='/Proizvodi/g/@g.Name'">@g.Name</a>
    }
</div>

<input class="Pretraga" placeholder="Pretraga..." onkeyup="Search(this)"/>

<div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
    <partial name="/Views/Proizvodi/_display.cshtml" model="@Roba.Take(Model).ToList()" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
    <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" class="ARButton1" style="width: 100%; display: block; text-align: center; padding: 20px 50px" href="/Proizvodi/Svi">Prikaži sve</a>
</div>

<script>
    function Search(el) {
        var v = $(el).val();

        if (v == null || v.length < 1) {
            $(".Proizvod").show();
            return;
        }

        $(".Proizvod").each(function () {
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(v.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and here is partial one:

```
@model List<AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties>>
@{ 
    AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties> User = null;
    List<AR.WebShop.Cena> ceneZaKorisnika = null;
    if(Security.isLogged(Context.Request))
    {
        User = AR.ARWebAuthorization.ARWebAuthorization.GetUser(Context.Request.Cookies["h"]).LocalUserClass as AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties>;
        ceneZaKorisnika = Termodom.GetVPCene(User.ID);
    }
}

<style>
    .Proizvod {
        width: 18%;
        margin: 1%;
        float: left;
    }

        .Proizvod .Thumbnail {
            width: 98%;
            height: 0px;
            margin: 1%;
            padding-bottom: 200px;
            background-image: url("/images/Termodom_Logo_White.svg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .Proizvod .Title {
            width: 96%;
            font-size: 1em;
            height: 4em;
            text-align: left;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 2%;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-top: 1em;
        }

    .Hobi {
        border: 2px solid gray;
    }

    .Standard {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }

    .Profi {
        border: 2px solid orange;
    }

    .Proizvod .cene {
        width: 96%;
        padding: 2%;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .Proizvod .vpcena {
        color: red;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .Proizvod .mpcena {
        color: green;
    }

    @@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .Proizvod {
            width: 48%;
        }
            .Proizvod .Thumbnail {
                padding-bottom: 100px;
            }
    }
</style>

@foreach (AR.WebShop.Product<AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties> r in Model)
{
    AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties tag = r.Tag as AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties;
    string klasa = tag == null ? "Hobi" : tag.Klasifikacija == AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties.Classification.Hobi ? "Hobi" : tag.Klasifikacija == AR.TDShop.ProductCustomProperties.Classification.Standard ? "Standard" : "Profi";
    <a href="/Proizvod/@r.Rel" class="Proizvod @klasa" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje...')" data-id="@r.ID" data-katbr="@r.CatalogueID">
        <div class="Thumbnail" style="background-image: url('@r.Thumbnail.Replace('\\', '/')')"></div>
        <div class="Title">@r.Name</div>
        @if(Security.isLogged(Context.Request))
        {
            AR.WebShop.Cena cen = ceneZaKorisnika.Where(x => x.RobaID == r.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if(cen == null || cen.VPCena <= 0)
            {
                <div class="cene">
                    <p class="vpcena">Pozvati za cenu</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="cene">
                    <p class="vpcena">VP Cena: @cen.VPCena.ToString("#,##0.00")</p>
                    <p class="mpcena">MP Cena: @Html.Raw((cen.VPCena * 1.2).ToString("#,##0.00"))</p>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </a>
}
```

here is layout with `_wait()` function

```
@{ 
    bool Jednokratan = false;

    AR.ARWebAuthorization.ARWebAuthorizationUser AutUser = null;

    if (Context.Request.Cookies["jednokratan"] == "1")
    {
        Jednokratan = true;
    }

    if (!Jednokratan)
    {
        AutUser = AR.ARWebAuthorization.ARWebAuthorization.GetUser(Context.Request.Cookies["h"]);
        if (AutUser != null)
        {
            AR.ARWebAuthorization.ARWebAuthorization.UpdateAliveStatus(Context.Request.Cookies["h"]);
            if (AutUser.Alive)
            {
                Program.Lista = CenovnikModel.UcitajCenovnik(Context.Request);
            }
        }
    }

    AR.ARStatistic.RaiseVisit(AR.ARDateTime.Now(2));

    if (Context.Request.Cookies["Visited"] == null)
    {
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions co = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions();
        co.Expires = AR.ARDateTime.Now(2).AddHours(6);

        Context.Response.Cookies.Append("Visited", "1", co);
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />








































    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-154885638-1"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-154885638-1');
    </script>


































    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Q-DHI0_kFx4L_d4CLO09MBzIYrRbvCpQRebNsi8zQxU" />
    @{
        object _desc = ViewData["Description"];

        if (_desc != null)
        {
            string desc = ViewData["Description"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(desc))
            {
                <meta name="description" content="TERMODOM - Centar građevinskog materijala. Online prodavnica namenjena svima. Gips karton ploče, stiropor, fasade, bavalit, azmafon, stirodur i još mnogo toga!" />
                <meta name="keywords" content="@desc" />
            }
            else
            {
                <meta name="description" content="@desc - TERMODOM - Centar građevinskog materijala" />
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <meta name="keywords" content="TERMODOM - Centar građevinskog materijala. Online prodavnica namenjena svima. Gips karton ploče, stiropor, fasade, bavalit, azmafon, stirodur i još mnogo toga!" />
            <meta name="description" content="TERMODOM - Centar građevinskog materijala. Online prodavnica namenjena svima. Gips karton ploče, stiropor, fasade, bavalit, azmafon, stirodur i još mnogo toga!" />
        }

    }
    <meta name="title" content='@ViewData["Title"]' />







    <title>TERMODOM - @ViewData["Title"]</title>

















    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Default.css?id=5" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Variables.css?id=3" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ARButtons.css?id=3" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/pedja.css?id=4" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/hashset.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/hashtable.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.4.js"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        html {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <partial name="pGallery" /> -->

    @if(AR.WebShop.Config.Get("POPUP_SHOW", null)[0].Value == "1" && Context.Request.Cookies["Visited"] == null)
    {
        <div style="position: fixed; width: 90vw; height: 90vh; 
                background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; top: 5vh;
                z-index: 999999999; left: 5vw" id="akcijaPop" onclick="$(this).fadeOut()">
            @Html.Raw(string.Join(' ', AR.Debug.Get("PopUp.html")))
            <button style="position: absolute; right: 50px; top: 20px; font-size: xx-large" onclick="$('#akcijaPop').fadeOut()">X</button>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="Header">
        @{
            string grad = "linear-gradient(45deg, #ff5b5b, #e04a4a)";

            if (Security.isProfiKupac(Context.Request))
            {
                grad = "linear-gradient(45deg, #FF9800 5%, #ff5b5b 8%, #e04a4a)";
            }
        }
        <div class="full-width" style="background: @grad">
            <div class="Third">
                <button class="button2 Desktop">&nbsp</button>
                <img style="float: left; height: 38px; margin-top: 6px; margin-right: 10px" class="Desktop" src="~/images/Termodom_Logo_White.svg" />
                <a style="float: left" class="button2 font-2" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje...');" href="/Home/IzaberiTip">Početna</a>
                <a style="float: left" class="button2 font-2" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje proizvoda...');" href="/Proizvodi">Prodavnica</a>
                <!--<a style="float: left" class="button2 font-2" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje...');" href="/Blog">Centar znanja</a>-->
                <a onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" style="float: left" class="button2 font-2" href="/Kontakt">Kontakt</a>

                @if (AutUser == null || !AutUser.Alive)
                {
                    if (Security.isProfiKupac(Context.Request))
                    {
                <a onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" class="button2 font-2" style="float: right" href="/User">Profi kutak</a>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((AutUser.LocalUserClass as AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties>).Type == (int)Termodom.UserType.Majstor || (AutUser.LocalUserClass as AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties>).Type == (int)Termodom.UserType.GradimKucu)
                    {
                <a class="button2 font-2" style="float: right; background-color: #ff9800" onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" href="/User/Logout">Izloguj se</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" class="button2 font-2" style="float: right; background-color: #ff9800; margin-right: 10px" href="/Porudzbina/Lista">Porudzbine</a>
                    }
                    else if ((AutUser.LocalUserClass as AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties>).Type == (int)Termodom.UserType.Administrator || (AutUser.LocalUserClass as AR.WebShop.User<AR.TDShop.UserCustomProperties>).Type == (int)Termodom.UserType.Administrator)
                    {
                <a onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" class="button2 font-2" style="float: right; background-color: #ff9800" href="/Admin">Control panel</a>
                    }
                }

                @if (Security.isProfiKupac(Context.Request) || Security.isJednokratanKupac(Context.Request))
                {
                <a onclick="_wait('Ucitavanje...')" class="button2 font-2" style="float: right; background-color: #ff9800" href="/Korpa">Korpa</a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="OpenMobileMenu()" id="MobileHeader" hidden>
        <img style="height: 30px; margin: 10px" src="~/images/hamburger1.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="vs7sa8vas" style="margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; color: white">
        <div style="background-color: #5a5cd4; width: 100%; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; max-width: 1000px; border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px; margin: auto">
            @foreach (string s in Program.GetGlobalMessages())
            {
                <div>@Html.Raw(s)</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="MasterWrapper">
        @if (Jednokratan)
        {
            <p style="text-align: center; color: #5a5cd4; font-weight: bolder; border-bottom: 2px solid #5a5cd4; padding-bottom: 10px">Trenutno se nalazite u modu jednokratne kupvine</p>
        }
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <partial name="pSideAction" />
    <style>
        #Footer button {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="Footer" style="background-color: whitesmoke; border-top: 1px solid gray">
        <div id="FooterInfo">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img alt="Termodom logo" src="~/images/Logo_White_Stroke.png" style="width: 50px" /><label style="margin-left: 5px; font-family: Raleway-ExtraBold">TERMODOM</label><br /><br>
                <p><b>Radno vreme:</b></p>
                <p>Ponedeljak - Petak / 07:00 - 16:00</p>
                <p>Subota/ 07:00 - 15:00</p>
                <p>Nedeljom ne radimo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h3>Kontakt</h3>
                <p>Centrala: Zrenjaninski put 84g</p>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" href="/Kontakt">klikni za broj</a>
                <p>email: info@termodom.rs</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h3>Mapa sajta</h3>
                <a style="display: block" onclick="_wait('Učitavanje');" href="/Home/IzaberiTip">Početna</a>
                <a style="display: block">O nama</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Proizvodi">Proizvodi</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Kalkulator">Kalkulator</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Blog">Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h3>Kupovina</h3>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Porudzbina/Find">Prati porudzbinu</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/User/Registracija">Uputstvo za kupovinu</a>
                <a style="display: block">Načini plaćanja</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Home/Dostava">Dostava</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block" href="/Kontakt">Reklamacije</a>
                <a style="display: block">Veleprodaja</a>
                <a onclick="_wait('Učitavam...')" style="display: block; color: white" href="/Proizvodi/SviProizvodi">Svi proizvodi</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="abba-watermark" style="width: 100%; background-color: #ff5b5b; color: white">
        <!--<h5 style="margin: 0; padding: 5px; text-align: center">Site by <a href="/Home/AbbaExpert" style="color: white !important">ABBAExpert</a></h5>-->
    </div>

    <div id="Wait" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; z-index: 999999; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)">
        <h2 style="z-index: 9999999; color: white; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 50vh; transform: translateY(-50%)"></h2>
    </div>

    <script>
        var ms = 0;

        function _wait(msg) {
            $("#Wait").show();
            $("#Wait h2").html(msg);
        }

        function OpenMobileMenu() {
            if (ms == 0) {
                $("#Header").css("transform", "translateY(50px)");
                ms = 1;
            } else {
                $("#Header").css("transform", "translateY(-100%)");
                ms = 0;
            }
        }

        function PretraziProizvod(element) {
            window.location.href = "/Proizvodi?Pretraga=" + $(element).parent().children("input").val();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Which part you need since it is complex. I will edit it now with posting index.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Your `function _wait(msg)` is defined near the very end of the HTML, and every `<a>` there includes `onclick="_wait(...)"`, so the browser has to load the entire page first. Nevertheless, it does not wait for all images to load. The browser starts loading images simultaneously while the HTML is being loaded. So you might have an impression that it has to load all images.

Attaching `onclick` on every `<a>` is expensive. As you use jQuery, you could easily handle the click event at the parent element that contains all the links concerned.

```js
$("#MasterWrapper").on("click", "a[href]", function() {
    $("#Wait").show().find("h2").html("Učitavanje\u2026");
});
```

Put this along with `<div id="Wait">` right in the beginning of `<body>` such that they exist before everything else is loaded.

Since you use partials, you need to find the shared layout. The code you just added does not show where `_wait` is.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? Mine begins navigation as soon as I click the link, without waiting for all images to load. I tested with slow 3G network speed emulation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After many times of testing your websit: https://beta.termodom.rs, to be honest, it's not that slow for me. There aren't so much pictures on it.

I think the loading div is a little bit annoying :P

Maybe you could just remove `<div id="Wait">...</div>` to have a better user experience.

```
    function _wait(msg) {
        //$("#Wait").show();
        //$("#Wait h2").html(msg);
    }
```

And why I suggest so?  I clicked to other pages without so much pictures, and the 'slow' loading still showed up and closed.

Moreover, browser will cache images automatically. If you insist to optimize, it might not worth. 
And other solution is increase server `bandwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of the images, they are VERY large - Total page download size 30MB+! so users on slow internet connection (SmartPhones) will be forced to wait.

You can use Chrome Light house (F12 on windows) to find optimization suggestions:

[image]